# Expo iOS prevent enable push notification

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to build an iOS application using Expo. When I run `expo build:ios`, the build fails because that is no Push Notification Key in the project. That is no key `notification` under `expo` tag in `app.json`.

### Why this happens?

When expo tries to build the app, it creates an identifier for the app on `developer.apple.com`. **It auto enable Push Notification for the app**. How can I disable that?

### Can't you "Let Expo handle the process"?

**No**. Expo tries to create a new Push Key if none where specified. The Apple Developer account that I'm publishing the app has reached the limit of 2 keys.

### Can't you use one of those keys?

**No**.

### Can't you revoke one key then create another?

**No**. They are in use.

Help! Pardon my poor choice of words.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I am also stuck on this point that how to go ahead by skipping the push notification step. I don't need the push notification for now. There is an option with eas build but wanted to know if there is any option to disable when building via expo build command.